Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<TInputDate, TDate>
I want to upgarde my (React, mui and formik) codes from mui v4 to mui v5. In mui v4 datepicker needs to be upgraded to x-date-pickers. Here is the codes mui v4 before upgrading within FormikKeyboardDatePicker.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import { UseFormikType } from './useFormikType';
import { KeyboardDatePicker, KeyboardDatePickerProps } from '@material-ui/pickers';

// Extend <KeyboardDatePickerProps> property type with "formik"
type FormikKeyboardDatePickerProps = Omit<Omit<KeyboardDatePickerProps, 'onChange'>, 'value'> & {
  formik: UseFormikType;
  id: string;
};

/**
 * Wrapper of <KeyboardDatePicker> to set value, onChange, error, helperText based on values managed by formik.
 * @param props default <KeyboardDatePicker> properties extended with "formik" parameter
 */
export default function FormikKeyboardDatePicker(props: FormikKeyboardDatePickerProps): JSX.Element {
  const { formik, id, format, ...other } = props;

  if (!id) throw new Error('FormikKeyboardDatePicker "id" property must not be empty');

  return (
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      id={id}
      value={get(formik.values, id, null)}
      onChange={(date) => formik.setFieldValue(id, date)}
      error={get(formik.touched, id, false) && Boolean(get(formik.errors, id))}
      onError={(error) => {
        if (error != null && error !== get(formik.errors, id)) {
          formik.setFieldError(id, error.toString());
        }
      }}
      helperText={get(formik.touched, id, false) && get(formik.errors, id)}
      onFocus={() => {} /* eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function */}
      onBlur={(event) => {
        formik.handleBlur(event);
      }}
      format={format ?? 'dd/MM/yyyy'}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}


and here is the code after upgrading to mui v5 within the FormikKeyboardDatePicker.tsx. I have provided the LocalizationProvider in the App.tsx with dayjs. Typescript raised an error for id as can be seen below after this code:
import React from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import { UseFormikType } from './useFormikType';
import { DatePicker, DatePickerProps } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';


type FormikDatePickerProps<TInputDate extends dayjs.Dayjs, TDate extends boolean> = {
  formik: UseFormikType;
  id: string;
} & Omit<DatePickerProps<TInputDate, TDate>, 'onChange' | 'value'>;

/**
 * Wrapper of <DatePicker> to set value, onChange, error, helperText based on values managed by formik.
 * @param props default <DatePicker> properties extended with "formik" parameter
 */
export default function FormikKeyboardDatePicker<TInputDate extends dayjs.Dayjs, TDate extends boolean>(
  props: FormikDatePickerProps<TInputDate, TDate>
): JSX.Element {
  const { formik, id, format, ...other } = props;

  if (!id) throw new Error('FormikDatePicker "id" property must not be empty');

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        id={id}
        value={get(formik.values, id, null)}
        onChange={(date) => formik.setFieldValue(id, date)}
        error={get(formik.touched, id, false) && Boolean(get(formik.errors, id))}
        onError={(error) => {
          if (error != null && error !== get(formik.errors, id)) {
            formik.setFieldError(id, error.toString());
          }
        }}
        helperText={get(formik.touched, id, false) && get(formik.errors, id)}
        onFocus={() => {} /* eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function */}
        onBlur={(event: any) => {
          formik.handleBlur(event);
        }}
        inputFormat={format ?? 'dd/MM/yyyy'}
        {...other}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


Here is where the component is used:
 <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
  <FormikKeyboardDatePicker
     formik={formik}
     id="invoiceDetails.paymentDate"
     variant="inline"
     inputVariant="outlined"
     fullWidth
     label="Payment date"
     disabled={promiseInProgress}
   />
 </Grid>

However after migrating to mui v5 i am getting this error about the id:
Type '{ disableFuture?: boolean | undefined; disablePast?: boolean | undefined; shouldDisableDate?: ((day: TInputDate) => boolean) | undefined; shouldDisableMonth?: ((month: TInputDate) => boolean) | undefined; ... 54 more ...; inputFormat: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<TInputDate, TDate> & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<TInputDate, TDate> & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)

Anybody can tell me where the problem may be?

where you have <DatePicker id={id} .... in FormikKeyboardDatePicker, simply remove the id prop there all together. It is not a known prop to the underlying Mui date picker component and it doesnt need to know either. That props is only interesting to the internal logic of  FormikKeyboardDatePicker itself. It does not need to be passed down.
